# How to display the VTABLE of a C++ class through GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, virtual-functions, vtable

I understand that a class will have a `VTABLE`, if it contains at-least one virtual function. I would like to see the contents of the `VTABLE`. Is there a way to display it ?

Specifically, is there an option in `gcc` to display the `VTABLE` of a class?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If the input file is say `layout.cpp`, the command `gcc -fdump-class-hierarchy layout.cpp` will produce a file `layout.cpp.class`. This file will display the VTABLE along with some other useful information.

Comment: Are you sure we should use gcc or we should use g++ for c++

Comment: Its g++ not gcc.

Comment: "Since GCC version 8.0 at least these two options were replaced:
-fdump-class-hierarchy is now -fdump-lang-class
-fdump-translation-unit ---> -fdump-lang-raw"

Comment: @user362515: Do you know if these options are still available in gcc version 9.0?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming it will really have a v-table (this is compiler dependent, and is not required or dictated by the standard) - you can inspect it with your debugger.

Why would you do that? If you're relying on it for anything other than curiosity - then **don't**.

Comment: Yes out of curiosity. Is there an option in gcc to display the vtable?

Comment: @LinuxPenseur you must mean gdb. I don't know. I know that on Visual Studio I saw it appearing once in a while when I was inspecting classes. I guess it depends on what symbol gcc attaches to it and whether you can find that symbol.